# Problem with Spacy - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sudachidict'

Tags: python, windows-10, python-3.7, spacy

trying to use Japanese model from Spacy.
This

```
import spacy
import ja_core_news_sm
nlp = spacy.load("ja_core_news_sm")
```

gives me

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sudachidict'**
and
**OSError: symbolic link privilege not held**

I reinstalled in administrator mode of cmd spacy and sudachipy==0.4.5 (as suggested in spacy docs), but didn't help.
How can I use this Japanese model?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `python -m spacy download ja_core_news_sm`?

Comment: yes, i tried that

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling `sudachidict_core` and reinstalling it in admin mode so that it can create the symlink from `sudachidict_core` to `sudachidict`.

Comment: Not sure if this worked for me, but it worked after I ran Python as admin.